# niffty model window effect in angularjs alone with responsive admin theme

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, modal-dialog

Have any of you implemented niffty model window effect in angularJs alone with responsive admin theme? If so, please let know how to go about doing this.

I know this question is duplicate.

helps much appreciated.

Comment: If  you know this question is duplicate, why do you still post the question?

Comment: coz i haven't got solution properly thats why. if u know the solution/idea whatever kindly share.. don't ask this kind of silly questions... stackoverflow is for sharing knowledge and asking for help only okay..!!  there's some kind of peoples here who marks questions as duplicate whenever they cross some similar question. @hbulens